# Need to ignore the values in a dynamic chart, that repete thenselfs

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts

I have a dynamic chart with percent of something along the project weeks. Each line is a different project, and i use this chart to compare their growing in percentage.

The problem is,some project are in the week 39, other in the week 30, and other at week 25, but when i put then in dynamic chart, the chart adopt the higher value for the weeks who will come.

[Dynamic Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtWfZ.png)

There is a way to automatic disappear these data values that repeat the data of the last week?

In this dynamic table of mine, line stop in the week 27, in the gray line

I tried to turn the data transparent, but when i use my slicer i reset the format, or ended up bugging all my chart.

Comment: have you set the chart to show empty cells as gaps? It would be useful to see a minimal example of sample data and the corresponding chart.

Comment: for cells in the range that need to be empty na() works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.